# Get Google Playstore app download links with python

Tags: android, python, search, beautifulsoup

I want to get the Playstore links of each app of a particular category.

Here's what I have tried:

```
r = br.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ART_AND_DESIGN/collection/topselling_free")
html = r.read()
soup = bsoup(html)

urlslist = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "card-click-target" })

fo = open('url.txt', 'w')

for url in urlslist:
        print "".join(["https://play.google.com",url])
        fo.write("".join(["https://play.google.com",url])+"\n")

fo.close()
```

But it doesn't return anything. urlslist is not populated either. I have tried with different tags and classes eg. `soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "title" })`, but that also returns a blank array.

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to iterate over:

> soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "card-click-target" })

Then extract `href` attribute of each `a` tag,

So change the following code:

```
for url in urlslist:
    print "".join(["https://play.google.com",url])
    fo.write("".join(["https://play.google.com",url])+"\n")
```

To:

```
for a in urlslist:
    link = "https://play.google.com" + a['href']
    print(link)
    fo.write(link + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! The urlslist is still returning an empty array though, any idea why?

Comment: @Yuu does `html = r.read()` gives you the page source code? because here i tested with `requests` library

Comment: yes, it does. How do you write it with the requests library?

Comment: `requests.get(url).text` will give you the source-code